# values not fetched in textboxes from database in php

Tags: php

I want all details of user to be fetched in textboxes to edit profile of user accordingly based on username stored in session I don't want which statement is wrong I am not able to fetch values in textboxes. Please help me.

Profile.php

```
<?php

include('connection.php');
//include('validation1.php');   
session_start();
if( !empty($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['username']))  
{  
 $username=$_SESSION['username'];
 $checkinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username=".'"$username"');
//$result=mysql_fetch_array($checkinfo);
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($checkinfo,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
$name =($result['name']);
    $address =($result['address']);
    $contact =($result['contact']);

    $state =($result['state']);
    $city = ($result['city']);
    $username =($result['uname']);
    $oldpass = ($result['opass']);

}
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $name =($_POST['name_txt']);
    $address =($_POST['address_txt']);
    $contact =($_POST['contact_txt']);
    $gender = ($_POST['gender']);
    $country = ($_POST['country']);
    $state =($_POST['state_txt']);
    $city = ($_POST['city_txt']);
    $username =($_POST['uname_txt']);
    $oldpass = ($_POST['opass_txt']);
    $newpass = ($_POST['npass_txt']);

    $insquery="UPDATE INTO profile(name, address, contact,gender, country, state, city,username,opassword,npassword) VALUES     ('$name','$address','$contact','$gender','$country','$state','$city','$username','$oldpass','$newpass')";
    $result=mysql_query($insquery); 

   // header("location:display.php");     
     if(!$insquery)  
    {  
    echo "Error Save [".mysql_error()."]";  
    }  
    /*else
    {
        // header("location:display.php");
    }*/
}
 ?>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<div align="center">
Registration Form
</div>
<div align="right">
          <?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
            {
                $s="Hello,".$_SESSION["username"];
                $r=$_SESSION["userrole"];
                echo $s;
            }    ?><a href='logout.php' id='logout'>Logout</a>
</div>
<table>
<tr>
<td><label>Name:</label></td>
<td><input name="name_atxt" type="text" id="name_atxt" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Address:</label></td>
<td><textarea name="address_txt" cols="40" rows="4" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Contact:</label></td>
<td><input name="contact_txt" type="text" id="contact_ntxt" value="<?php echo $contact; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Gender:</label>
<td>
<input type=radio name=gender value="male" id=male >Male</br>
<input type=radio name=gender value="female" id=female >Female</br></td>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Country:</label></td>
<td><select name="country_select" id="country_select">
<option value="0">--select a country--</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="USA">USA</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>State:</label></td>
<td><input name="state_atxt" type="text" id="state_atxt" value="<?php echo $state; ?>"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>City:</label></td>
<td><input name="city_atxt" type="text" id="city_atxt" value="<?php echo $city; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Username:</label></td>
<td><input name="uname_txt" type="text" id="uname_txt" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>Old Password:</label></td>
<td><input name="opass_txt" type="password" id="opass_txt" value="<?php echo $oldpass; ?>"   /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label>New Password:</label></td>
<td><input name="npass_txt" type="text" id="npass_txt" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="btn1" /></td>
<td><input name="reset_btn" type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
```

I want values already stored in database should be fetched in textbox of particular user who is in session and it is not fetching values in textbox.

Comment: `UPDATE` should be `INSERT` or your syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$checkinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username=".'"$username"');
```

should be

```
$checkinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username='$username'");
```

Also your `UPDATE` syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

SQL UPDATE Statement:

```
 UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Comment: Don't give `w3schools`'s link to user. They contains wrong code with examples.